# grails AJAX call to database

Tags: mysql, ajax, grails, groovy

I'm new to grails. I'm trying to develop a simple page with just a dropdown that when the user makes a selection an AJAX call is made to the database. Thing is that there is are no domain files at all in my application. I only have controllers and views and I intend to keep it this way. So I basically want to use grails to issue a mySQL Select statement through AJAX and get the results.

Comment: app with only direct db access is much more complicated that using domains, btw

Comment: You'll spend more time trying not to use Domain Classes than just using them for what grails wants them for.  Consider some other frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the below:

1. From the AJAX call (I prefer jQuery), make the call to the controller action method.
2. In the controller's method you can use [Groovy SQL](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL)  to execute your query.
3. Return the result as JSON object and display it whatever way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL for a tutorial on executing SQL using the built-in Groovy SQL library. You can then create a controller action and map your resultset to JSON, and you won't even need a GSP view file. Here's an example Controller class that will do basically what you need.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class MyController {

    def sessionFactory

    def myAction() {
        def sql = new Sql(sessionFactory.currentSession.connection())
        sql.execute("select ....") //execute SQL using Groovy SQL

        render(contentType:"application/json") {
            //render your DB query results as JSON
            //you could also use JsonBuilder to render JSON output
        }
    }
}
```